# Is it possible to make quarterly returns in hedge funds?

Tags: hedge-funds

I wanted to know if I can make quarterly returns by investing in Hedge funds, if  yes how? By quarterly returns I mean investing in hedge funds and getting returns in one to three months time. Usually I see hedge funds returns are yearly.

For example I invest $25 Million with say XYZ firm in USA, I am particularly interested to know is it really possible to get returns from $25 Million in the range of 5 to 10% in 3 months.

Comment: Can you be more specific? Realized or unrealized returns?  Do you mean quarterly versus monthly or annually? You mean _guaranteed_ returns?  Certainly you _can_ make returns in hedge funds, but I suspect there's something more to your question than just a yes/no answer.

Comment: What do you mean "Make quarterly returns"? What do you mean by "Hedge funds"? It looks like this question, even if properly defined, will be very broad and opinionated; neither quality is very suitable for this site.

Comment: See related question here: https://money.stackexchange.com/a/76190/44232

Comment: Re: your additions - I bet you're seeing _reported_ gains which would be annualized.  It depends on the fund as to whether you can withdraw earnings quarterly or at any other interval (or at all). They are not regulated so there's not an answer that will apply to _all_ hedge funds.

Comment: Your latest edit has not really cleared anything up.  You're asking if hypothetical gains of 5-10% in one quarter are possible with hypothetical hedge fund XYZ?  Yes, returns of 5-10% are _possible_ with many investments, and hedge funds tend to have greater returns (and risk) that most other investments.  But nothing is _guaranteed_.  You are just as likely to _lose_ 5-10% as well.

Answer (score 2):

**Your edit indicates that you may not yet be ready to get heavily involved in investing.** I say this because it seems you are not very familiar with foundational finance/investing concepts.

The returns that you are seeing as 'yearly' are just the reported earnings every 12 months, which all public companies must publish. Those 'returns' are not the same as the earnings of individual investors (which will be on the basis of dividends paid by the company [which are often annual, sometimes semi-annual, and sometimes quarterly], and by selling shares purchased previously.

Note that over 3 months time, investing in interest-earning investments [like bank deposits] will earn you something like 0.5%. Investing in the stock market will earn you something like 2% (but with generally higher risk than investing in something earning interest). If you expect to earn significant amounts of money in only 3 months, you will not be able to without taking on ***extreme*** levels of risk [risk as high as going to a casino].

Safe investing takes time - years. In the short term, the best thing you can do to earn money is by earning more [through a better job, or a second part-time job], or spending less [budget, pay down high interest debt, and spend less than you earn].

I highly recommend you look through this site for more budgeting questions on how to get control of your finances. If you feel that doesn't apply to you, I encourage you to do a lot more research on investing before you send your money somewhere - you could be taking on more risk than you realize, if you are not properly informed.